# Do I need to use xss_clean if I'm only allowing integers?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is just something I was wondering about.

If I have a rule where I am only allowing integers as input, such as:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item_id', 'item id', 'required|is_natural_no_zero');
```

Is it necessary to run xss_clean on it? I don't see how XSS could be an issue in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you probably wouldn't need to.  Using the XSS clean features are more geared towards inputs where people can enter text and symbols.  If you require int only or alpha only or alphanumeric, they won't be allowed to enter symbols that would be a part of XSS.  On the other hand, if you wanted to run EVERY input through an XSS filter, it couldn't hurt.